# to alter or create a new table in cassandra to add new columns

Tags: database-design, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am using DSE cassandra.

I wanted to add new attributes to the existing table.

I wanted to know what is the best practice to achieve this? Should i be adding new columns to existing table or creating new table?

What are the pros and cons for either approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding columns is fine. See the [ALTER statement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html). Unless you need to change your primary key, you should not need to create/migrate to a new table.

Comment: Good answer Blake.  The only thing I would add, is that alering the structure of a column family (table) could lead to a corrupt schema in older versions of Cassandra.  But that issue has been fixed for quite a while (as of version 1.1.15, I think) and shouldn't be an issue any longer.

Comment: Thanks blake and Bryce